# Is a clopen set a paraconsistent object?

Tags: general-topology, logic

I hope this question makes sense, the doubt just arose out of curiosity.

Knowing that there are sets that are open and closed at the same time, I wonder if this has any relation to paraconsistent logic, since we could say that these clopen sets have properties of the type ($p\wedge \neg p$) if we call $p$ as the statement "to be an open set". Can we deduce something from the point of view of the logic of an clopen set?

It is clear to me that this would not be feasible if the negation of "being open" is not "being closed".

Definition of open: $\forall x \in A$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $B_{\delta}(x) \subseteq A$.

Negation of this definition:  $\exists x \in A$ such that $\forall \delta > 0$, $B_{\delta}(x) \not \subseteq A$.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes, and why was the answer below accepted, reading this I thought the op was hinting at something deeper.

Comment: @Jakobian: it is stated that $p$ means "to be an open set". However, it then goes on to imply that $p\land\lnot p$ means "to be a clopen set". The problem is that $\lnot p$ does not mean "to be a closed set". While the complement of an open set is a closed set; it is not the case that "being open" is the negation of "being closed".

Comment: @robjohn I think the whole point was to go outside of classical logic, so $\lnot p$ can just as good mean that "to be a closed set"

Comment: Since the empty set and the whole set are both closed and open, there is no way that they would be negations. If they are asking about some alternative logic, they will need to define that fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is exactly as you say: the negation of "being open" is not "being closed". Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}$:
$$A = (0, 1) \cup \{2\}.$$ Note that there does not exist any open ball centered at $2$ contained in $A$, hence $A$ is not open.

Now, consider $\mathbb{R} \setminus A = (-\infty, 0] \cup [1, 2) \cup (2, \infty).$ Note that there does not exist any open ball centered at $0$ contained in $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$, hence $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is also not open. Since $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is not open, $A$ is not closed.

Therefore, $A$ is a set that is not open, but also not closed, and we see that the negation of "being open" is not "being closed".

Comment: I think what op meant is that if $p$ means some set is open/closed, then $\lnot p$ means the same set is closed/open and the implications coming from the fact that $p\land \lnot p$ in this "logic" doesn't lead to a contradiction, which is an interesting question. How does this answer it?

Comment: @Jakobian The point of this answer is that the statement "if $p$ means some set is open/closed, then $\neg p$ means the same set is closed/open " is not true. If this statement were true, then any set which is not open would have to be closed. By giving an example of a set $A$ that is not open or closed, we see that this statement is false. The takeaway is that what OP refers to as $\neg p$ is not really the negation of $p$ at all, so there is no $p \wedge \neg p$ to worry about.